# Different output shape of Conv2D between tf.keras and keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

It might be a dumb question since I'm new to Keras and Tensorflow.

I have this simple model:

```
classifier=Sequential()

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

classifier.summary()
```

When running with `tf.keras.*` (like `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`) classes, `summary` shows the first layer as:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 21, 21, 32)        896
```

but when running with `keras.*`(like `from keras.models import Sequential`) classes. `summary` shows the first layer as:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 62, 62, 32)        896
```

Why do they give different output shapes?

I'm using tensorflow 2.0.0 and keras 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Well that is related with the `kernel_size` actually. First let's check

## Example 1:

```
classifier=Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

classifier.summary()
```

note that the little change in `Conv2D` that is about in your code it was `classifier.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))` and in the other one has `kernel_size = (3, 3)`.
Example 1 gives the output shape as

> (None, 62, 62, 32)

## Example 2:

Let's change it to your version

```
classifier=Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

classifier.summary()
```

results in,

> (None, 21, 21, 32)        896

The conclusion is, `tf.keras` api and standalone `keras` are interpreting `kernel_size` differently. Notice that I have get the both results with `tf.keras` api.